# PCL Visualizer error

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I make(using rosmake) the PCL visualizer tutorial - (http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcl_visualizer.php#pcl-visualizer)
I get this error-

/opt/ros/fuerte/include/pcl-1.5/pcl/visualization/common/common.h:39:24: fatal error: vtkCommand.h: No such file or directory

It seems that ros is unable to find vtk modules.
Can anyone help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39444/pcl-visualizer-error/) by [gpsinghsandhu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2834/gpsinghsandhu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2012-07-21

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gpsinghsandhu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2834/gpsinghsandhu/) on 2012-07-24**:
Yes I am using Fuerte on ubuntu precise
The command returned---All system dependencies have been satisified
I also checked for libvtk5-dev which is installed on my system.
Is there a way to directly link libraries like libvtk5-dev using CMakeLists.txt which may help me.
And thanks for your response

**Comment by [gpsinghsandhu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2834/gpsinghsandhu/) on 2012-07-24**:
Also i don't know how to comment joq's answers so i just commented here. No post a comment link on your answer

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-25**:
You can edit your own question, often a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok I found the answer. I explicitly added the vtk modules and libraries to CMakeList and it worked fine. I added the two following lines at the end

include_directories(/usr/include/vtk-5.8)

target_link_libraries(pcl_viz ${PCL_LIBRARIES} libvtkCommon.so libvtkFiltering.so libvtkRendering.so)

here pcl_viz is my executable

I would prefer that ros take care of these things as in the standalone PCL

---

Originally posted by [gpsinghsandhu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2834/gpsinghsandhu/) with karma: 231 on 2012-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-09-13**:
That is not a good solution. As you say, ROS should take care of it properly. If it does not, please open a defect ticket.

**Comment by [gpsinghsandhu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2834/gpsinghsandhu/) on 2012-09-16**:
how exactly should I do that

**Comment by [KARTHIK MURUGAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/3722/karthik-murugan/) on 2012-12-08**:
hi gpsinghsandhu, i have the same problem. i tried adding to CMakeLists as u mentioned. i get an error :-Cannot specify link libraries for target "pcl_tutorial" which is not built by this project.In ur case pcl_viz is the name of your package or the node(program.cpp)??a detailed qn s my account,HELP

**Comment by [gpsinghsandhu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2834/gpsinghsandhu/) on 2012-12-12**:
please provide the link for the detailed question

**Comment by [KARTHIK MURUGAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/3722/karthik-murugan/) on 2012-12-12**:
here it is :-http://answers.ros.org/question/49978/package-using-pcl-make-error/

**Comment by [KARTHIK MURUGAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/3722/karthik-murugan/) on 2012-12-12**:
Please pour in ur suggestions for this another question at : http://answers.ros.org/question/50146/mapping-between-pointcloud-and-image/

**Comment by [Vittorio88](https://answers.ros.org/users/2132/vittorio88/) on 2013-08-18**:
This fixes the issue for me perfectly! Thanks!
This issue is still present in ROS Groovy on Ubuntu Raring 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You appear to be using ROS Fuerte. What OS are you running?

On my Fuerte/Oneiric system, that header is defined in `libvtk5-dev`.

What does this return?

```
$ rosdep check visualization_common
```

EDIT: That tutorial is for *standalone* PCL, not for PCL with ROS. It does *not* say to build using `rosmake`, because that would not work. For that tutorial follow the directions for "Compiling and running the program".

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-07-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2012-09-13**:
I have the same problem and this returns "All system dependencies have been satisified."

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem with visualization (ROS FUERTE, Ubuntu 12.04LTS). It seems to be some dependency missing with the ros-pcl version. What I did, I removed PCL from ros (sudo apt-get remove ros-fuerte-pcl) and downloaded the PCL version from the website (trunk, in my case) and build it with "USE_ROS true" (important to use USE_ROS, or you will get some reference errors. Dunno why)

Than I simply removed the pcl and ros_pcl from the manifest.xml and used the standard CMakeList.txt method to include PCL. In my case,

```
  find_package(PCL 1.5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS segmentation filters visualization)
  include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
  add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
```

and finally

```
  target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PCL_LIBRARIES} )
```

Works perfectly, also with visualization.

---

Originally posted by [Markus Eich](https://answers.ros.org/users/1686/markus-eich/) with karma: 202 on 2012-10-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2013-02-16**:
I was bale to build PCL in normal way. But how to build PCL from trunk with USE_ROS true ??

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-10-14**:
@Sai did you manage to find how to build with USE_ROS true?

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2013-10-16**:
Please look at this link.
http://www.pcl-users.org/How-to-integrate-PCL-with-ROS-as-an-external-library-td4026185.html#a4026213